# Programming Function Keys

Tags: keyboard

Is there a way to program the Function keys?
For example, I would like to assign (for instance <kbd>F6</kbd>) to a directory path that always opens when I click <kbd>F6</kbd>. 
This would be very useful when I'm saving files all the time in the same directory.

But more generically, I would like to assign F keys to any sequences of commands executed serially (like stacks). 
Such feature is, in my opinion, one of the most important for enhancing productivity, and nonetheless, no operating system that I know offers it.

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: Which Desktop environment are you using?

Comment: You can set up F keys to link to open a specific directory in your file browser, or run any arbitrary command (including a shell script). I'm not sure, though, if you can use an F-key to jump to a specific directory in a save dialog or similar. I'd assume not, but you may be able to hack it with creative use of shell scripting.

Comment: Sorry Ehsaan - Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Thanks for the response. Assume this:  download file type A, open, edit and THEN because this is file type A, BY clicking Fa, saves this file in directory specified in Fa. File type B would be saved in Fb, etc. t if I do the same for another type of file, I click another F key and end of story

Comment: And by the way, where can I learn more about programming F keys? Thanks much!

Comment: Detail: there would be no need of clicking SAVE in the application menu.  Just a F key would do the job. If there is no such thing, how hard it would be to hack it?

Comment: why not bind f6 to the command `nautilus /path/to/directory` in settings -> keyboards -> shortcut -> custom shortcut

Comment: @SergioMaia What you're asking here is *really* sophisticated and won't really ever be included in a native DE, as cross-app compatibility will be a huge issue. You're going to have to do a lot of shell scripting and event handling to do this. It's not going to be an easy feat at all, I'm afraid. Look at shell scripting at the very least, as well as commands like `xdotool`. They might be able to help you at least start your journey.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but if you use 'Keyboard Shortcuts' provided by default in Ubuntu, you can set F* keys to your liking. You can assign a command to perform, for example if you want <kbd>F6</kbd> to open `/home/whatever/Music`; in the command section you add `nautilus /home/whatever/music`
If you want a series of commands you can write them as a script located somewhere in your computer.
Hope it helps.

I'm sorry I can't provide these images in English but they're just to know where to click.

[image: First image.]

[image: Second image.]

Comment: In Norwegian...
"søk på datamaskinen" means "Search your computer".
"Tekstoppføring means" "Text Entry".